# Invalid positioning of HTML5 form validation bubble in Chrome

Tags: validation, html, google-chrome

Anyone have an explanation why the Form Validation Bubble is positioned with a large offset in Google Chrome when attempting to validate a form hosted in a jquery UI dialog? You can observe that the positioning works ok when removing the javascript call that creates the dialog. It's working fine in Firefox and Opera.

http://jsfiddle.net/oliverw/Z6xAz/

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug: http://crbug.com/94786. FWIW It seems to be fixed in Chrome 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This been confirmed to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86541) in Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Chrome bug, seems they already saw it. I hope they can fix it for next version....

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660840
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680019